# Installed 12.04 dual boot with 10.04, fails to boot 10.04

Tags: dual-boot

I installed 12.04 alongside of 10.04 this evening, not an upgrade, just a side by side install. After doing a few updates, I re-booted to access 10.04. Scrolled down in the grub menu and selected the 10.04 and pressed enter.

Got a page with several lines and what stood out was:

```
Target file system does not have /sbin/init
```

then a prompt with:

```
(initramfs)
```

I've come across several posts around the net with booting to a live CD and trying to fix the hard drive to running a few script files to fix the problem. Is there a single point solution to repair this?

John

Answer (score 1):

I did some more digging and came across a blog that stated if the partition started on zero instead of one, it is possible that it could cause similar symptoms as this. It recommended running Gparted to correct the issue. I located my system rescue CD (downloadable from [System Rescue CD](http://www.systemrescuecd.org)) and ran it. Accessed Gparted. The partition that would not boot was starting at zero so I reduced the size of the partition by one meg, started the partition at one and initiated the action. Because this was an almost 300 gig sized partition, it took about 6 hours for it to complete. After it finished, I rebooted the computer and on the grub screen, I chose the partition I had problems accessing from before and it booted as designed.

Problem solved.